# Reading xml string and populating list collection

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, c#-3.0

I need to read the xml string and assign the values to list collection. I need to read the question node and assign it to the list collection variable. Similarly read the answer and assign it to list collection variable. Currently the Question and answer is getting overriden and not traversing to the next node. Could someone tell me what the problem is ?

Following is the code

```
 XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            var fataQuestionnaire = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16""?>
                           <FatcaQuestionnaire xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                             <QuestionAnswers>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>What is your source of wealth?</Question>
                                    <Answer>I am italian </Answer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>What is your occupation and name of employer?</Question>
                                    <Answer>Bestinvest</Answer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>Do you have a business or residence in?</Question>
                                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>How long have you lived outside of Albania</Question>
                                    <Answer>5 years</Answer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>Do you return to Albania on a regular basis</Question>
                                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                                    <SubQuestionAnswer>
                                         <Question>How frequently?</Question>
                                         <Answer>every year</Answer>
                                    </SubQuestionAnswer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>Do you have family in Albania?</Question>
                                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                                    <SubQuestionAnswer>
                                         <Question>Family relationship?</Question>
                                         <Answer>My parents lives there</Answer>
                                    </SubQuestionAnswer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>Are you connected to the government of Albania?</Question>
                                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                                    <SubQuestionAnswer>
                                         <Question>Nature of association</Question>
                                          <Answer>I was an ex minister</Answer>
                                    </SubQuestionAnswer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                                  <QuestionAnswer>
                                    <Question>Do you send or receive money from Albania?</Question>
                                    <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                                    <SubQuestionAnswer>
                                         <Question>How often and why?</Question>
                                         <Answer>Every month for my parents to live with.</Answer>
                                    </SubQuestionAnswer>
                                  </QuestionAnswer>
                             </QuestionAnswers>
                           </FatcaQuestionnaire>";

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(fataQuestionnaire));


            xmlDocument.Load(reader);

            XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
            if (xmlRoot != null)
            {
                XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xmlRoot.SelectNodes("/FatcaQuestionnaire/QuestionAnswers/QuestionAnswer");
               List<string> questionanswer = new List<string>();

            if (xnlNodes != null)
                foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
                {
                    if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
                        questionanswer[0] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

                    if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
                        questionanswer[1] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;

                    if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
                        questionanswer[2] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

                    if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
                        questionanswer[3] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;
                }

              }
            }
```

Comment: You sample does not make much sense - you are trying to set values to non-existing elements of `List` (like  `questionanswer[2]=...`) - please makes sure code at least looks like one that can work. Also consider debugging to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer[0] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer[1] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer[2] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer[3] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;
}
```

with

```
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer.Add(xndNode["Question"].InnerText)

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer.Add(xndNode["Answer"].InnerText);
}
```

You need to add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you first created the List it was empty and therefore it had no objects to add to. You are trying to set values to non-existent fields in the Array.

So:
change the code from this:

```
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer[0] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer[1] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer[2] = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer[3] = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;
}
```

To this:

```
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
    questionanswer.Add(xndNode["Question"].InnerText);

  if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
    questionanswer.Add(xndNode["Answer"].InnerText);

}
```